# Deleting an item from RecyclerView causes shuffling or duplicating other items

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, rowdeleting

I have a recyclerView that users can add or delete item rows and that rows saving the Firebase Firestore. Adding function works fine but deleting function does not. I created an interface (Listener) through `PairDetailRecyclerAdapter`. It contains `DeleteOnClick` method which have myList and position parameters. Also I have a `deleteData` method through my viewModel for deleting documents from Firestore. When i clicked the delete button on Firebase side everything is OK but on recyclerView side items duplicating themselves or shuffling

Here is the codes:

Interface and onClickListener from `PairDetailRecyclerAdapter` :

```
  interface Listener {
    fun DeleteOnClick(list: ArrayList<AnalyzeDTO>, position: Int)
}
```

---

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AnalyzeViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.rrRatioText.text = "RR Ratio: ${list[position].rrRatio}"
    holder.itemView.resultText.text = "Result: ${list[position].result}"
    holder.itemView.causeForEntryText.text = "Reason: ${list[position].reason}"
    holder.itemView.conceptText2.text = "Concept: ${list[position].concept}"
    if (list[position].tradingViewUrl != null && list[position].tradingViewUrl!!.isNotEmpty()) {
        Picasso.get().load(list[position].tradingViewUrl)
            .into(holder.itemView.tradingviewImage);
    }
    


    holder.itemView.imageView.setOnClickListener {
        listener.DeleteOnClick(list, holder.layoutPosition)
    }
```

---

deleteData from ViewModel :

```
    fun deleteData(position: Int) {

    var chosenPair = ozelSharedPreferences.clickiAl().toString()
    val currentU = Firebase.auth.currentUser
    val dbCollection = currentU?.let {
        it.email.toString()
    }
    database.collection(dbCollection!!).document("Specified").collection("Pairs")
        .document(chosenPair).collection("Analysis").get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            val newList = ArrayList<String>()
            if (result != null) {
                for (document in result) {
                    newList.add(document.id)
                    database.collection(dbCollection!!).document("Specified").collection("Pairs")
                        .document(chosenPair).collection("Analysis").document(newList[position]).delete()
                }
            }
        }
}
```

---

Overrided Listener in `PairDetailActivity`

```
    override fun DeleteOnClick(list: ArrayList<AnalyzeDTO>, position: Int) {
    viewModel.deleteData(position)
    list.removeAt(position)
    recyclerA.notifyItemRemoved(position)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun deleteItem(i: Int, context: Context) {
        question = dataList[i] as Questionio //this my model 
        dataList.removeAt(i)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

//
this code works for me
in fact, it would be better if you did it as a model and it would be suitable for mvvm architecture.

Comment: What does "i" refer to ? Also why did you declare "question" ? Sorry i can't get it.

Comment: "i" will be the position of the element. 
question is my list.

Comment: If you look at my 'DeleteOnClick' method it is doing exactly same thing with yours but even though i replace notifyItemRemoved with notifyDataSetChange, it does not work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: it works fine for me, if you find out the answer, can you please get back to me. But my advice to you is to look at the model structure.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lfum5cO8LHA&t=480s&ab_channel=SociedadAndroide

Comment: hi, I guess i find what causes to this. in my `deleteData`function from ViewModel i'm retrieving data one more time additionally. So that causes duplication

Comment: glad you can solve the problem